# Deploying via Skaffold dev to a new GCP account fails cause tries Skaffold tries to deploy to old GCP account

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, skaffold

I had a project that I deployed to GCP via Skaffold. Now I had to change the GCP user, so I created a project in GCP of the new account (the...@gmail.com)

I connected via gcloud login to the new user:
[image]

I created a new context on Kubernetes associated with that account and it's project
[image]

In addition, I changed all yaml files in my project to have the correct project id

But when I try to deploy via Skaffold, it still tries to connect to the old account.
[image]

Do you know how can I fix it?

Comment: Hi, before you tried to deploy with `Skaffold`, have you tried to use some `gcloud` or `kubectl` commands? Are they targeting new or old resources (old project resources)?

Comment: So you are building using the `googleCloudBuild` builder.  Skaffold attempts to retrieve the active user's credentials, and otherwise falls back to the _application default credentials_.  Could you run with `-v info` to enable slightly more verbose logging?  Do you have any `CLOUDSDK_*` or `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_DEFAULT` environment variables set?

Comment: I did try to use gcloud and kubectl commands before doing the scaffold dev, but they worked as expected but didn't seem to be helpful.
I neither have CLOUDSK_* nor GOOGLE_APPLICTION_DEFUALT env vars set.

I did solve it by removing the "old" user from Gcloud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue by removing the old user with the command

```
gcloud auth revoke USERNAME
```

In addition I changed my gcloud default credentials via:

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```